# How do I manipulate objects?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Oblivion, you could grab objects with the Z-key, or the Telekinesis spell.

I've tried the Z key in Skyrim, but couldn't seem to grab anything.

And then I see this:

So clearly manipulating objects exist in some fashion, I'm just unsure of the appropriate keybinds. Any ideas?

Comment: Would be cool if you could use this to sell them an item and steal it back. Then this could double as a speech booster as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hold the Activate key (<kbd>E</kbd>, ⓧ, or Ⓐ by default for PC, PS3, and Xbox, respectively). The <kbd>Z</kbd> key defaults to your Dragon Shout/Racial Power on PC. Be careful with that.

Comment: For those of us who've remapped our keys, what *command* is that?

Comment: @Ben Activate. Edited that into the answer.

Comment: Any idea if there's a way to rotate items once they're being "held"?

Comment: I'd recommend banging them on the ground, tables, or people.

Comment: @IanPugsley Careful with that.  Sometimes the object will shake loose from your grip.

Answer (score 10):

Hold down the button bound to 'Activate/pick-up.'

- For Xbox, that's <kbd>A</kbd>
- For PC, that's <kbd>E</kbd>
- For PS3, that's <kbd>X</kbd>