# Pick things up but not take them

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I manipulate objects?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34968/how-do-i-manipulate-objects)

In the following video, there is a bucket exploit in the game that allows you to steal.  Pressing "A" takes the item and puts it in my inventory, but I want to move it and not put it in my inventory.

This will also be useful for organizing things in your house.

How can you do this?

*note, I don't want to take it into my inventory and then drop it on the ground hoping it lands in the correct spot. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/34968/6914