# Can you not do the bucket trick on Xbox?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I manipulate objects?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34968/how-do-i-manipulate-objects)

There is a trick to steal things by putting a bucket on someones head:

I do not know of any way to pick an item up like that on the 360. Its clear in the video that it is the PC version, so is it not possible on a console?

Answer (score 0):

I only have the pc version, but to pick stuff up to hold it is just holding the Use key down for a couple seconds. So, on pc, to pick something up I just hold down E and after a second I begin carrying it.

I'm presuming it's the same with the Xbox, just with the appropriate Use button.

Comment: Cool, I will try that out and see if it works.